springBoot + Thymeleaf: set Locale
I have this configutation that is working fine:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public MvcConfig(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource);
        return bean;
    }
}

but when I try to set the locale like this:
 @PostMapping("/blogs")
    public String handleSubmit(@RequestParam("langCode") String langCode) {
        // Handle the selected option here
        if (FR_LANG.equalsIgnoreCase(langCode)) {
            LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.FRENCH);
        } else if (ES_LANG.equalsIgnoreCase(langCode)) {
            LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("es").build());
        } else if (PT_LANG.equalsIgnoreCase(langCode)) {
            LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("pt").build());
        } else {
            LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        }

        // Redirect to a different page or return the same page
        return "redirect:/blogs";
    }

the locale is not set

Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46521387/573032

That is what the LocaleChangeInterceptor is for. Don't write your own controller let the LocaleChangeInterceptor do its work (which it already should do but you are messing around with it). Change the paramName to langCode (as apparently that is what you are using) and ditch your controller.

The LocaleContextHolder will give you the current locale set, but not resolve a new one to use. Try the following:
@PostMapping("/blogs")
public String handleSubmit(@RequestParam("langCode") String langCode,
                           HttpServletRequest request,
                           HttpServletResponse response) {

    if (langCode!= null && !langCode.isBlank()) {
        LocaleResolver localeResolver = RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request);
        if (localeResolver == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("No LocaleResolver found");

        try {
            localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, StringUtils.parseLocale(langCode));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.debug("Ignoring invalid locale value [{}]: {}", langCode, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return "redirect:/blogs";
}

StringUtils#parseLocale see documentation here will parse langCode according to language and region, thus possible values would be en_US, es_ES, de_DE, ... you get the idea ;) If you set a locale which your application doesn't support it will always fallback to the default, so need to worry about that.

Don't. Changing the Locale is the task of the LocaleChangeInterceptor, which does all of this already.

Using request parameters is an ugly solution, at least in my opinion - but of course would work to a special degree. However, if you wanna be in full control this is the way to go, no polluted URLs and you still remain Master of the Universe ;).

You are still using a request parameter, regardless the use of the controller or the interceptor you are still in full control.

If you send it as a form url encoded value within the POST body there is no URL query parameter as described in all examples out there. I confess, I don't know for sure whether the LocaleChangeInterceptor is capable of inspecting only the URL parameter or post body content as well, but Spring definetly goes the way for URL query parameter in general, as you can see for example with continue as query parameter after authentication success. I'm no fan of this style, it's ugly and may cause issues for bookmarks (except you request a full redirect afterwards, which isn't better at all).

It uses getParameter under the hood which doesn't care where the parameter comes from URL or form. So instead of making claims better investigate. In generally parameters are better for bookmarks then hidden parameters in forms, cookies etc. because all state is in the URL (but that is a different discussion). Here you are doing exactly the same as the LocaleChangeInterceptor does so re-inventing the wheel and adding maintance cost to your application.
